# Find a variable value inside the database using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I use laravel framwork
inside this framwrok I already have a variable named $a 
and $a values can be 117,125,114.
On onther hand I already have a databse table which has filed that contains values 145,117,119,888.
I want to match any of variable to any of data in database.
which command i have to use???

Comment: Dadash soaleto farsi too comment bepors man nafahmidam chi migi :D :D

Comment: too framworke laravel
ye moteghayer daram be esme $a ke meghdaresh hast ',117,125,114,'
hala ye field az table ham darim meghdaresh masalan hast ',145,117,119,888,'
hala mikham ye doone az 3 ta data moteghayere a too yeki az meghdaraye field morede nazar bood ok she

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
$data = DB::table('your_table_name')->whereIn('contains', array(1, 2, 3))->get();
```